# Tags component for Salesforce Visual Force page on custom object

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

I have enabled Tags on a custom object, which has a Visual Force page override for edit/view in place of the standard page layouts.

Is there way to add the standard Tags component to the VF pages, or do I have to manually code something ?

Comment: why dont you try topics instead of tags

Comment: <apex:page>
 <topics:widget entity="0D5x00000009Fhc" customUrl="http://mywebsite/TopicViewTestPage?topicId="/>
</apex:page>

Comment: Can i add as an answer for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Topics instead of tags .A VF widget can be added as shown below

```
   <apex:page> <topics:widget entity="0D5x00000009Fhc" customUrl="mywebsite/TopicViewTestPage? topicId="/>
</apex:page>
```